# Are comments on deleted posts flaggable?

Tags: support, flags, deleted-comments

If I click the flag button on a comment in a deleted post, it will show the overlay "I am flagging this comment as" and the options, but after I select one and press "Flag Comment," the usual "Thanks, we'll look at it" orange box does not appear.

So, are comments in deleted posts flaggable?

Comment: Related: [Are soft-deleted answers candidates for flagging?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97669/are-soft-deleted-answers-candidates-for-flagging)

Comment: Bug report: If anybody see that, here ( https://serverfault.com/review/low-quality-posts/125065 ) I was able to add comment to a bug report. Sorry I won't open a new question, because I won't risk this wonderful robo-downvoter collective to eliminate me from the site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like it; I tried it and my browser got back a success response. I'm not getting the "thanks" box either though, even when I flag comments on non-deleted posts. I don't remember if it ever happened for comments; it might just be when flagging posts