# What do we do with phantom flags?

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, moderator-tools

I just encountered a situation while moderating Stack Overflow that I've encountered several times before:

- User flags question or answer
- Flag is dismissed by a moderator (either way)
- Flag is disputed fifteen minutes after being dismissed. Dismissed flag re-appears in the queue with the new dispute under it.

I can think of two reasons why this happens:

1. Caching
2. Users not refreshing the tools page after being away for a little while

I'm not sure if this is a bug or not. Rather, I'm wondering what we should do with these?

I don't want to mark a previously declined flag as 'helpful' by dismissing the new 'disputed' (phantom) flag as 'helpful'. However, I don't want to mark the dispute as unhelpful. It seems like I would be declining the same flag twice by doing so?

Or, reverse the scenario for a flag previously marked as helpful.

The most recent example would be flags on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7377628/mysql-update-primary-key/7377641#7377641). Should users be able to dispute flags that have been dismissed, or is what I'm seeing simply an artifact of caching? More importantly, how should these be handled?

Comment: Should be handled the same way that closed questions are... if you don't refresh the page, then it shows an error if it is already closed.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107449/deleted-answer-still-appearing-in-the-flagged-queue and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105697/should-it-be-allowed-to-flag-deleted-answers - do those account for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to some *other* causes of phantom flags (see above), a change will be going in at some build in the future, to ensure you can't add "this flag is invalid" votes *after* the flags have been cleared. Basically, just closing down another 2-person race between the 10k tools and (most likely) the moderator tools.

Comment: Schweeeeeet :) Thanks Mark. I didn't see the other two meta posts creep in after this one, mostly due to being busy. The changes you describe should take care of it.