# Deleted answer still appearing in the flagged queue

Tags: support, status-completed, flags

I've seen this question [Should it be disallowed to flag deleted answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105697/should-it-be-allowed-to-flag-deleted-answers) but the situation here is different.

This answer still shows up in the flagged post queue. But **it's been deleted by a moderator** and not the OP himself.

[image]

[image]

I've refreshed the page a few times - is this cached or a flag that just wont go away.

Do other users see this particular post in the queue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Interesting - it was deleted an hour ago, but 30 seconds after it was deleted, another user flagged it (presumably a 10k user had the flagged-posts screen open at the time). This was enough to keep it active on the 10k screen, and it subsequently attracted another 4 flags. But indeed, it has been dealt with!

Normally, the act of a moderator intervening (such as deleting the post) will wipe the flags - and indeed this did happen here; however, it was still possible for other users to flag it *after* it was deleted.

I will try to ensure that in the future, only *custom* flag reasons can be used on deleted posts; this should avoid this unnecessary scenario (i.e. the user flagging it after it was deleted would be simply told "this post has been deleted").

Comment: I hope _custom_ flag reasons include the generic moderator flag that allows a comment, we'll still need to be able to do that.

Comment: @Lance that is exactly what I mean, and is the *only* one I think we'll need for a deleted post, no?

Comment: Yep, agreed....

Comment: Just to confirm, will this [address this question as well](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107449/deleted-answer-still-appearing-in-the-flagged-queue/107450#107450)?

Comment: @GraceNote you seem to have linked here to ... here. Can you clarify which other question you mean?

Comment: ...I hate it when that happens. Give me a moment...

Comment: Here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105808/what-do-we-do-with-phantom-flags