# Deleted answer appearing in 10k flag queue

Tags: bug, 10k-tools, not-an-answer

I was going through the 10k tools to review [Not an Answer flags](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged?flagtype=answernotananswer) and I noticed that I am seeing a [deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19927370/how-to-use-url-as-locator-in-command-select-window/20604181#20604181) in the queue.

> [image]

The answer was deleted 4 hours ago by the user but it is still showing in the queue with a total of 13 flags.  I found this [previous question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107449/deleted-answer-still-appearing-in-the-flagged-queue) about a deleted answer being flagged after the deletion which caused it to remain in the queue, that says [tag:status-completed,  is this a new issue?

Should flagged answers that have been deleted by a user still appear in the queue?  Is this a bug?