# Flagging deleted posts one can not see oneself

Tags: discussion, support

(related: [Should it be disallowed to flag deleted answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105697/should-it-be-disallowed-to-flag-deleted-answers))

I recently stumbled upon this question: [Userscript to add a 'flag' button to deleted Stack Exchange posts](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14244/userscript-to-add-a-flag-button-to-deleted-stack-exchange-posts)

Someone is asking for a userscript, that allows him to flag deleted answers (a hobby of his). Meaning deleted posts that one himself can not see. The site itself does not offer such a functionality.

Two questions: Is this allowed behaviour? Should the site allow one to flag posts through API POST requests even though the website does not offer the functionality directly?

Comment: You might wish to clarify in the title and perhaps body that you are talking only about deleted questions that you yourself cannot see. You can always flag deleted posts which you **can** see, and there is occasional need for this.

Comment: @tchrist edited my post

Comment: Allowing this will set back any of the progress that we've made against Undo getting Rickets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, asking for such a script and creating one is allowed. We cannot dictate what software someone writes or runs on their own computer.

However, if the 'feature' were to be abused then the user will find themselves on the receiving end of a moderator intervention. The developers may choose to simply block the possibility by adding a reputation check when flagging deleted posts to make sure only those that can actually see the post can flag.

In short, I don't really see an issue here.

Comment: It wasn’t immediately clear from the question (although I figured it out) that the OP is talking only about deleted posts which one cannot see, since if one can see them, one can certainly flag them.